# A random variable X has range from $(0,a)$. Show that $Var(X)\le a^2/4$

Tags: probability

A random variable X has range from $(0,a)$. Show that $Var(X)\le a^2/4$.
The given hint is to show $E[X^2]\le aE[X]$ first, and use that to show $Var(X)\le a^2[\beta(1-\beta)]$, where $\beta=E[X]/a$.
I don't know how to start. I've tried using Cheyshev's inequality but it doesn't work. Can anyone give me a hint how to start? Any concept I've been missing?

Comment: is that all the information in the question?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I've edited some typos. And yes, that is all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$E[aX-X^2]=E[X(a-X)]\ge 0$$

$$Var(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2\le aE[X]-E[X]^2$$

Answer (score 0):

You know that $Var(X)=\int_0^a(x-\mu)^2dx=\int_0^ax^2p(x)dx-\left(\int_0^axp(x)dx\right)^2$, where
$p(x)\geq0$ is the probability distribution and $\mu=E(X)$. Hence,
$$
Var(X)\leq a\int_0^axp(x)dx-\mu^2=\mu(a-\mu)=a^2\beta(1-\beta)=-a^2(\beta^2-\beta+1/4-1/4)=-a^2(\beta-1/2)^2+a^2/4\leq a^2/4
$$
since $0\leq x\leq a$.